# Where do service permissions come from

Tags: users, services, init

I'm trying to broaden my knowledge of the events surrounding system startup. I see that there are many process which are started without root level permissions. e.g. rsyslogd is listed as running under user syslog. What controls this permission level. For example, if I wanted to start rsyslog as root, how would I go about changing the startup of that service.

p.s. Starting rsyslog as root is only an exercise. I know better than to do that in practice, but it illustrates the granularity I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to old-style SysV init scripts, the startup script or the configuration file specifies the user to drop privileges to. The script itself is run as root, but will often contain a `su - <user>` or `runas <user>` command within it to drop privs to the specified user. I'm not familiar enough with upstart of StartUp style service definitions to say it works the same, but I would be surprised if the mechanism were that much different.